# Printing out array lists

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I messed up trying to print out this array list what am I doing wrong I've tried multiple times but when ever it prints it outputs null.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.text.NumberFormat;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 //Class header

 public class ShoppingCart {

     // Start of main method

     public static <Item> void main(String[] args) {

         // Declare and instantiate a variable that is an ArrayList that can hold
         // Product objects

         ArrayList<Product> item = new ArrayList<Product>();

         // Declare necessary local variables here

         String Name = null;
         double Price = 0;
         int Quantity = 0;
         String Seller = null;

         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

         String Shop = "yes";

         // Write a print statement that welcome's the customer to our shop

         /**
          *
          * create a do while that will be keep looping as long as user wants to
          * continue shopping
          */

         Product im = new Product(Name, Price, Quantity, Seller);

         // do while loop start

         do {

             // Ask user to enter product name and store it in appropriate local
             // variable

             System.out.print("Please Enter the Product Name: ");

             Name = scan.next();

             // Ask user to enter product price and store it in appropriate local
             // variable

             System.out.print("Please Enter the Price of the Product: ");

             Price = scan.nextDouble();

             // Ask user to enter quantity and store it in appropriate local
             // variable

             System.out.print("Please enter the Quantity: ");

             Quantity = scan.nextInt();

             // Ask user to enter product manufacturer name and store it in
             // appropriate local variable

             System.out.print("Please Enter the Manufacturer: ");

             Seller = scan.next();

             System.out.print("Would you like to continue shopping?");

             Shop = scan.next();

             // create a new Product object using above inputed values

             Product item2 = new Product(Name, Price, Quantity, Seller);

             // add above created Product to the ArrayList cart if Product has
             // available stock

             // if stock not available inform user requested product is out of
             // stock

             // Ask user whether wants to continue shopping

             // set the do while loop to continue to loop if Yes option is
             // selected

         } while (Shop.equals("Yes"));

 System.out.println("Product                     Unit Price         Quantity         SubTotal");
 System.out.println(Name + "                " +     (Price) + "     " + Quantity + "         " + (Price * Quantity));
 System.out.println("00"); System.out.println(item);

 // do while loop end
             // header for shopping cart contents

 // print details of each product added to the ArrayList

 // calculate total price of the shopping cart

 // print the total price of the shopping cart


     }// end of main method

      }// end of Shop class
```

Comment: Please post your code again and use the `{}` button to format it in a codeblock instead of a quote. - Now please only show the relevant code (amongst others: remove the comments and whitespace. We're not interested in that).

Comment: If you never add anything to the `item` list then it's going to be empty when you print it. Were you expecting something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why are you doing this

```
public static <Item> void main(String[] args) {
```

SHould be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

To print the ArrayLIst just do this

```
System.out.println("Name\tPrice\tQuantity\tSeller\tTotal")
for (Product p : item){
    double total = p.price * p.quantity;
    System.out.println(p.name + "\t" + p.price + "\t" p.quantity + "\t" + p.seller + "\t" + total);
}
```

But first you need to add something to the list

```
Product item2 = new Product(Name, Price, Quantity, Seller);
item.add(item2);
```

Or even a cleaner looking idea would be override `the toString` method in the `Product` class

```
public class Product {
    String name;
    String Seller;
    double price;
    int quantity;

    public Product(String name, double price, int quantity, String seller){
        this.name = name;
        this.seller = seller;
        this.price = price;
        this.seller = seller;
    }

    public String toString(){
        double total = p.price * p.quantity;
        return name + "\t" + price + "\t" quantity + "\t" + seller + "\t" + total;
    }
}
```

To print from list just do this.

```
for (Product p : item){
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's so much a _can't_ as just a _why???_ That creates a generic type parameter called `Item`, but it's never used. It _does_ compile, but it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

its because you never add the item2 to the arraylist item
just add

```
item.add(item2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors in your program.

First off, the reason nothing is being printed when you try printing your arraylist is because you never add any element to your array list, to do so you must use the following method.

```
arrayListName.add(elementToAdd);
```

Secondly your main method is incorrect, instead of

```
public static <Item> void main(String[] args) {
```

it should be

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
```